# How to track user interaction with a video using JS?

Tags: javascript, video

I have a video on a website that I have set up using the `<video>` tag. I have enabled `controls` on the video and was hoping to find a way to track user interactions with the video, for example using the controls or skipping portions of the video.
I know there are options in google analytics that allow you to track this but due to certain limitations that option can't be used. I was hoping if there is a way using only JS to do this?

Comment: Are you looking to detect when a user fast forwards/rewinds etc? Or are you looking for a way for that information to be saved so you can access that data later without sending that information to Google Analytics?

Comment: Handle whatever events you want, and log whatever data you want to wherever you want.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: @imvain2 yes I am looking to track when a user fast forwards/rewinds, pauses, etc. without sending them to google analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different events such as `seek` and `seeking` and `volumechange` as per the Mozilla docs. You'll have to be more specific for your use case, but this seems to be enough for what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Events

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when a user seeks in a video is it possible to track from which timestamp to which timestamp they skipped the video?

Comment: @Ahijit 

const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('seeked', (event) => {
 let o = document.getElementById('output');
 o.innerHTML = event.target.currentTime;
});